# How to change connection string in web.config for entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, entity-framework

I need to deploy WCF. Database is SQL Server 2008 R2. Access to database is only possible from app server because of Windows Authenticaton (sql server authentication not work).
I need to change my connection string to new data source i tried but not successfull.
i have connection address and everything what i need.

My connection string :

```
<connectionStrings><add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyDatabase.csdl|res://*/MyDatabase.ssdl|res://*/MyDatabase.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=myMachine-LAPTOP;initial catalog=MyDatabaseName;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings></configuration>
```

to delete connection string and generate new is not possible, because i have not access from dev computer and app server dont have visual studio to try it from there.
i need help how to change it.

Comment: Did you try to use XSLT-transformation?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change connection string by opening configuration file with notepad..

Comment: Are you using Entity Data Model..If so, then you will have to make change in the configuration file of that edmx and web both